# Init SQL on WildFly

Tags: sql, configuration, jboss, init

In my actual Application Server ( Glassfish 4 ) I set the Oracle schema  in field "Init SQL"  of datasource.

I would know how to do this in WildFly 9.

How to run an initial statement for a datasource before getting any connection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The  field "Init SQL" from glassfish is the field  "New Connection Sql" for WildFly on Connection tab of JDBC Datasources.

Example:

New Connection Sql: ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=MY_SHEMA